# How to integrate $\int_{C} \frac{1}{|x|^t}dx$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to integrate $\int_{C} \frac{1}{|x|^t}dx$, where $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$, $0< t< n$, and $C = n$ copies of $[0,1]$. I know how to compute it for balls. Basically for $n \leq 3$, just use change of variables, then for higher dimension. use the coarea formula. However, those methods do now work for cubes.

Comment: you want $[0,1]^n,$ not $n$ copies

Comment: That is what I mean by $n$ copies. What are you thinking of ?

Comment: $n$ copies is vague, $[0,1]^n$ is clear.